# I can't install module from kivy-garden

Tags: python, macos, kivy

I'm trying to create a python program that graphs the input from GUI using kivy.
I successfully installed kivy-garden from my terminal but somehow my terminal does not recognize the "garden" command and I can't install kivy graphing tool through terminal.
First I pip installed kivy-garden. Then this showed up

```
Requirement already satisfied: kivy-garden in 
./.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages (0.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in 
./.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from kivy-garden) (2.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in 
./.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests->kivy-garden) 
(1.26.3)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in 
./.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests->kivy-garden) 
(2020.12.5)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in 
./.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests->kivy-garden) 
(2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<5,>=3.0.2 in 
./.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests->kivy-garden) ( 
4.0.0)
```

Since it was already installed, I went ahead and executed the next command,

```
 `garden install matplotlib
```

` Here was the result.

```
pyenv: garden: command not found
```

I did exactly what it said on the YouTube tutorial video and I'm stuck here for days.
Can anybody help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons behind it. I have faced this kind of problem many times, why don't you try this way:

```
1. restart the terminal, if still not working try to install another library also
2. garden install graph
3. check kevy-garden by following steps if its installed or not

            i.    type 'python' in terminal // it will open python shell in terminal
            ii.   import kivy
            iii.  print(kivy. __version__)
```

it will show the version of kivy-garden if it's installed else it will tell it's not installed.
you should try another way to install it again.